# Fontawesome Chrome v43 Wordpress v4.2.2 display issue

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, font-awesome

On a new site I've built I'm getting reports that the Fontawesome characters are displaying as squares on the latest version of Chrome (v43.0.2357.124m), this is on a Windows 7 machine. I'm unable to replicate the issue with the same Chrome version number and platform. I'm using fontawesome version 4.2.0 and the site is built using WordPress 4.2.2.

I've checked the archive and this seems to have been an ongoing issue with Chrome and Fontawesome for some time, most of the posts here are over a year old. Is there a solution that works today?

Many thanks
Kevin

Comment: ...how are you including FontAwesome? It's impossible for us to help you without more info.

Comment: I'm using SASS, I've got a library folder in my theme directory, in there is my scss folder and my fonts folder. All font awesome files are in fonts. My main styles.scss file imports partials/typography and that imports ../../fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/scss/font-awesome